# How do I label columns and format all columns in a gt table?

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to add a few finishing touches to this table but not sure how to. See below for code and current output -

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

group = c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g3")
n = c(100, 233, 444, 555)
df <- tibble(group, n) %>% 
    mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) 

df %>% 
    gt(rowname_col = "group") %>%
    cols_align(align = "center", columns = c(n, pct)) %>% 
    grand_summary_rows( columns = n, fns = list(Total = "sum"), fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 0)) %>% 
    grand_summary_rows( columns = pct, fns = list(Total = "sum"), fmt = ~ fmt_percent(., decimals = 0)) %>% 
    fmt_percent(columns = c(pct), decimals = 1) %>% 
    fmt_number(columns = c(n), decimals = 0) %>% 
    tab_style(
        style = cell_fill(color = "lightgreen"),
        locations = cells_body(
            rows = 3:4,
            columns = TRUE
        )
    )
```

[image]

I would like to -

1. Add a column label called "Group" in g1 - g3 groups column
2. Add the lightgreen label to all columns (including the groups)
3. Change the "sum" text in the grand total to "Total"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a label to your row group column aka the "stub" using `tab_stubhead`. Similarly, to add your fill color style to the row group column, you could target it using `cells_stub`. Finally, there are several options to set the label for the grand summary row, e.g. you could use `fns = list(Total = ~ sum(.))`

```
library(gt)

df %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "group") %>%
  cols_align(align = "center", columns = c(n, pct)) %>%
  tab_stubhead(label = "Group") |> 
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = n,
    fns = list(Total = ~ sum(.)),
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 0)
  ) %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = pct,
    fns = list(Total = ~ sum(.)), 
    fmt = ~ fmt_percent(., decimals = 0)
  ) %>%
  fmt_percent(columns = c(pct), decimals = 1) %>%
  fmt_number(columns = c(n), decimals = 0) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightgreen"),
    locations =
      cells_body(
        rows = 3:4,
        columns = everything()
      )
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightgreen"),
    locations =
      cells_stub(rows = 3:4)
  )
```

[image]